# Benchmarking Mysql cluster using sysbench

Tags: mysql, benchmarking

When benchmarking a mysql clustering using sysbench, do you have to install sysbench on every machine in the cluster to benchmark the cluster performance? Is there a way to install sysbench on one machine and use it to benchmark other mysql servers on different machines?

If, for example i have HAProxy as the load balancer for the cluster which is configured on its own machine separate from the cluster nodes, then can you use the HAProxy machine only to benchmark the entire cluster since HAProxy machine will be doing the load balancing and acts as the window to all other cluster nodes?

I am knew to MySQL benchmarking, and new to using sysbench.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to install sysbench on every SQL node, your intending to use and benchmark. (not the NDB data node).

**HAProxy & ProxySQL are two different things but you can get the best of both worlds if you really want to.**

HAProxy is a very fast and reliable solution offering high availability, load balancing, and proxying for TCP and HTTP-based applications. It is particularly suited for very high traffic web-sites and powers quite a number of the world's most visited ones. HAProxy(High Availability Proxy) is an open source load balancer which can load balance any TCP service. It is particularly suited for HTTP load balancing as it supports session persistence and layer 7 processing.

ProxySQL is an open-source MySQL proxy server, meaning it serves as an intermediary between a MySQL server and the applications that access its databases. ProxySQL can improve performance by distributing traffic among a pool of multiple database servers and also improve availability by automatically failing over to a standby if one or more of the database servers fail.

To run the sysbench benchmarks, follow this guide:
https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Sysbench

To setup the ProxySQL:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-proxysql-as-a-load-balancer-for-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04

Set Up Highly Available HAProxy Servers with Keepalived and Floating IPs: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-highly-available-haproxy-servers-with-keepalived-and-floating-ips-on-ubuntu-14-04

To create multi-node SQL Cluster: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-multi-node-mysql-cluster-on-ubuntu-16-04

Set the engine to use sysbench - `ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER;` on mysql client.
you will need to create database and then prepare the sysbench before running it. Good luck!